# Can I use qq or q instead of qw in the following perl script?

Tags: perl

The output for the following script would be the present date like " 26 Dec Mon"

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
@months = qw( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec );
@days = qw(Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun);
($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
print "$mday $months[$mon] $days[$wday]\n";
```

Comment: If I use qq or q can I get same output as if like using qw

Comment: why are you asking?  no, you can't.  you also can't just replace `print` with `open` and have it work, or use `:` instead of `;`.  different parts of the language do different things, and you can't just arbitrarily switch them around.

Comment: My biggest question here isn't "why would you want to do that?" but "why didn't you just try it?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No.

`qw(a b c)` is a shortcut for `('a', 'b', 'c')`. It returns a **list** (of words, that's what the `w` stands for).

`q()` is simply another way to write **single quotes**, i.e. `q(a b c)` is identical to `'a b c'`. It returns **one string** without interpolation.

`qq()` is a way to write **double quotes**, i.e. `qq(a b c)` is identical to `"a b c"`. It returns **one string** with interpolation.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators for details.

The `q()` and `qq()` syntax is sometimes used when the string to be quoted contains (lots of) single and/or double quotes and you want to avoid escaping them:

```
my $s1 = "This \"contains\" quotes - \" - and \"is\" no fun to \"type\"";
```

vs.

```
my $s2 = qq(This also "contains" quotes - " - but "is" easier to "type");
```

Comment: If I use qq it will be stored in double quotes.Doesn't That work fine with the print function.

Comment: no, that would set `$months[0]` to `' Jan Feb Mar ...'`.

Comment: Okay, Thanks I got the answer.

Comment: s/similar/identical/g

Comment: @gudipati ramu, Re "*If I use qq it will be stored in double quotes*", This demonstrates a lack of fundamental understanding. Things aren't stored "in double quotes".  Both `'abcdef'` and `"abcdef"` produces the string `abcdef`. This is what's stored. It doesn't matted how the string got constructed.

Comment: @ikegami   I am new to perl Programming. I know that both 'abcdef' and "abcdef" produce string and also I know the difference between the both of them. Actually when I am learning Perl through Tutorial I couldn't get the exact information about q,qq,qw. That's why the question was asked.
Anyway Thanks for you Explanation.

Comment: @gudipati ramu, My point is that they produce *exactly the same string*. You claimed that a double-quoted string would be stored different, but that's not true.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you. I just did "s/similar/identical/g".

Comment: @ikegami   My wording was wrong in that comment where I mentioned that will be stored in double quotes.

Comment: `w` in `qw` could also stand for whitespace, since that is what delimits words.

Answer (score 3):

```
qw(...)
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
split(' ', q(...))
```

so it's obviously not equivalent to

```
q(...)
```

or

```
qq(...)
```